# Template and My File Differences

Tags: php, css, codeigniter

I'm trying to figure out why I'm getting so many errors on the page getting validated and why I'm getting my page to look like the template. The CSS files are exactly the same. For some reason the div with a class of login-footer clear isn't inside the login box model like it is in the template and the label for the two text boxes aren't quite aligned right.

http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.kansasoutlawwrestling.com%2Fkowmanager%2Findex.php%2Fauth%2Flogin&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Template Page: http://www.kansasoutlawwrestling.com/admintemp/login.html

My Page: http://www.kansasoutlawwrestling.com/kowmanager/index.php/auth/login

Or maybe it has to do with the controller and view.

Edit: The errors on the page were fixed only issue remaining is the alignment difference with the login-footer div difference.
Config/asset.php: http://pastebin.com/195usTQG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page won't validate because of all the PHP errors that are output before the DOCTYPE is even loaded.  It looks like you're using a constant that isn't defined, but I really can't say more without digging through your source.

Start by checking the file `config/asset.php` like the errors suggest.

Comment: That issue was fixed i"m just trying to figure out why the login-footer isn't inside the box.

Answer (score 1):

Your Template has this code at the top:

```
<div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">

    <h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>
    <p>Severity: Notice</p>
    <p>Message:  Use of undefined constant APPPATH_URI - assumed 'APPPATH_URI'</p>
    <p>Filename: config/asset.php</p>
    <p>Line Number: 15</p>

</div>
```

This is causing the error. This should be at the bottom. Because w3 Validator first read the Doctype definition on line 1. Unfortunately on line 1 there is no Doctype definition (DTD) found.

Comment: That issue was fixed i"m just trying to figure out why the login-footer isn't inside the box.